# Prototype JS - Calculate remaining width

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, width

For a div like this

```
<div style="width:200px;">
    <span>Element 1</span>
    <span>Element 2</span>
    <span>Element 3</span>
    <span>Element 4</span>
    <span>Element 5</span>
</div>
```

How I can calculate with javascript or Prototype JS remaining space on the right of the last span element. Span elements have a dynamic width and I will have to find out remaining empty space on the right on the last line from the div.

Comment: ... why are you still using Prototype?

Comment: It's a old website that is using Prototype. Anyway pure javascript would be fine as well.

Comment: Referring users asking questions abrout PrototypeJS to jQuery is not helpful and may lead to another holywar

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like the following:

```
var div = $("divId"); // Get the extended div element
var width = div.measure("width");
var offset = div.cumulativeOffset();

var span = document.createElement("span");
div.appendChild(span); // Append an empty span at the end of the last line
var spanOffset = span.cumulativeOffset();

var emptySpace = (width - (spanOffset.left - offset.left)) % width;
span.remove();
```

which may become a bit more complicated depending on the div style (borders, padding, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would do it starting from the parent div...

```
var t = $$('div span')[4];

var width = t.up().getWidth() - t.getWidth();
```

You can modify the CSS selector in `$$()` to your liking but I was basing it on the HTML you provided.

http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/getWidth/

Comment: In the same line might be more than 1 span element, this would work for 1 span per line.

Comment: if you wrap the whole line in one `<span>` then you can calculate the width of that element instead of all the spans